# How can I connect my docker containers on the default bridge network?

Tags: docker, networking, connection

I have 2 docker containers running on my windows 10 machine. I have been able to interact with them by binding container ports to host ports, but now I want to dockerize another application that I have been using to interact with these containers. Up until now I have been configuring the urls using localhost, but after moving the third application to a container that will no longer be an option, so I did some research and decided to use the default bridge network. I checked that all 3 containers were in the network:

```
[
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "c570148be95b87b5bc768de573e85c25fa4584df2c5df5c63b2d317decabe651",
    "Created": "2021-03-22T07:49:32.2206325Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "38beb0863d86dab0f014ef9f1ad85f02efa7fb96520455df6f6ea6b5519f60cc": {
            "Name": "my_redis",
            "EndpointID": "58a6cfab6f233ac39c9b043c660124fd9cb98970f99f154ad8b3774a3356e71b",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "70fe60faa0dc3b853edcf2005e16d6219015eafa1c65d48aebd57256ff329f2b": {
            "Name": "rabbitmq",
            "EndpointID": "ed4ac901659785eebfd58de4056efd51addd19eda8c184a38632f1486c178e53",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "b34359519bbf0253af3eba8e800a1bcabeb3cfe6e5cc5007679c6f632f1d4820": {
            "Name": "app",
            "EndpointID": "3363141459cc7eebeca1651b047ed3af81c4af37c3706dfa74e5eadb6f95f302",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
```

]

From what I can see, icc is enabled and all 3 containers are on the network. I used the IPv4Address in the configuration in app: STA_REDIS_HOST = 172.17.0.3 (with and without the /16 at the end, because I'm not sure what it means), and it seems as if the ip is being resolved to something else, because I get the following error:

```
 Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.
```

I don't know where 127.0.0.1 but it looks like the private ip of the host machine.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is resolved since it's configured somewhere in your application either as `127.0.0.1` or as `localhost`. The host IP should be without `/24`, the server will also be available on a host `my_redis` (the name of the service is the host name)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get how you are trying to connecting one container to other...

[docker_bridge_network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) demonstrates pinging one container to others by using bridge network

Comment: I'm getting the IPv4Address for each container using the docker network inspect bridge command, and then trying to point one container to another using this ip address. So far it's not working.

Comment: are you trying to point from inside a container of the network bridge?